# How to save large python object with pickle in joblib parallel processes

Tags: python, pickle, joblib

I'm trying to save large object (~7GB) in pickle binary file with in each joblib parallel process. However, Joblib raises MemoryError.

I have enough RAM (256GB) and storage (4TB). I have assigned joblib 12 cores. I have monitored memory and the memory is just okay (more than the half of total memory remains empty).

The code is simply structured like

```
import pickle
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def do_something(arg1, arg2):
    ...
    pickle.dump(save_somthing, open('somefile.p','wb'), protocol=-1)
    return 1

JobList = ['a1','b1','c1','d1',\
           'a2','b2','c2','d2',\
           'a3','b3','c3','d3']
arg2 = 'sth'
Parallel(n_jobs=12)(delayed(do_somthing)(i, 'sth') for i in JobList)
```

I want it to end my job normally but I don't know how to allocate (or allow) joblib to use more memory

++)
Environment
OS : Ubuntu 18.04.2 (64-bit)
Python : Python 3.6.8 (GCC 7.3.0)

```
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 568, in __call__
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 534, in _cached_call
    out, metadata = self.call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 734, in call
    output = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "02_trj_ConvertToPickle.py", line 65, in to_pickle
    configArray = np.zeros((nAtoms,9))
MemoryError
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "02_trj_ConvertToPickle.py", line 106, in <module>
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=numCPUcores,verbose=32)(delayed(to_pickle)(i, directoryBufferProcessing) for i in fileList)
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 934, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/yjw0510/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
MemoryError
```

Comment: Such kind of tasks is very sensitive to: a) OS, b) python version and 32/64 bitness. Please add information

Comment: @AlexYu I have added the information

Comment: I'm not sure for 100% and I never had an experience with `pickle`-ing really big files. AFAIK pickle was never intended for work with files of such size. Can you: a) post full stack-trace of error, b) can you try to `pickle.dump` such file without joblib? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, pickle did dump the size over 4GiB with `protocol = -1` option (and, without `joblib`, I have tested `pickle.dump` and the program did `pickle.dump` normally). Checking full print of error needs me to run the program once more. It needs a day to do that. I will do and update it.

Comment: @AlexYu Fortunately, I have not closed the terminal that raised the error. So I updated the post.

Comment: It looks like: `File "02_trj_ConvertToPickle.py", line 65, in to_pickle` - is the source of `MemoryError`. What is the value of nAtoms? Can you run `np.zeroes((nAtoms, 9))` without everything else?

Comment: @AlexYu Firstly, Some of the parallel processes actually success without error, only some of them fails. Secondly, That's the pre-allocation of the array before I replace the elements. Lastly, I got no error when I don't use joblib. Thanks.

Comment: quick remark you are writing stuff to a binary file in parallel, but i am not sure how pickle deals with the racing conditions. Additionally, I don't see a close file statement (maybe in the dots). If you are only using numeric content I would suggest you ook at h5py format and give each dataset a unique group to write to. This has the added benefit of using a file format that is designed to for larger files and can be used across platforms.

Comment: @JiwoongYu I don't doubt your words. And looking on stacktrace I see that MemoryError is reised on attempt to initialize `numpy.array` of 9x`nAtoms` size. One could suppose that `nAtoms` varies greatly so that one task works sufficiently and another fails. Only you can prove or disprove this hypothesis.

Comment: Can you post code of `to_pickle` function from `02_trj_ConvertToPickle.py`?

Comment: @AlexYu : I don't mean to be aggressive but I just want to clarify myself. `to_pickle` function is too lengthy to write down here. nAtoms is integer varying file-by-file but it's around `40000`. I highly doubt `joblib` has some default limitation for memory for each processor.
@GlobalTraveler : Thank you for suggestion, but I have compulsory reasons to use `pickle`. Also, I have closed the `f=open(~)` file with `f.close()` in `...`  part. I have written (also read different files) to different pickle file in each process. So I think race condition has no relevance here.